# Username formatting issue when using Spotify API + RSpotify gem

Tags: ruby, spotify

I'm running into a strange issue with the Spotify API, specifically the Playlist search (using `RSpotify::Playlist.find()`). I'm providing a playlist ID and the owner's ID, but in some cases the owner's username has characters that require escaping.

This user for example: https://open.spotify.com/user/andy%3F%21

Their username is `andy?!`, which, when escaped, turns to `andy%3F%21`. However, when I try and retrieve one his playlists using the Playlist search, I'm getting a 404 error, `Invalid username`. I've triple checked, and I'm definitely providing the escaped character version of the username (using `CGI.escape`).

I also tried going to the Spotify Web API Console and `andy%3F%21` works correctly there. Is this some bug with the RSpotify gem?

Comment: Is it possible that you're accidentally escaping twice - i.e. escaping the `%`? Are you able to see the exact HTTP request made by the RSpotify client?

Comment: I've been trying to read the RSpotify source to see what's going on... unfortunately the code is a bit confusing (I'm not very knowledgable about some of the ways they've structured their code). However, if I don't escape the userID, it's showing the URI as completely unescaped.. so the only thing I can think of is if RSpotify uses an incorrect or buggy escape method.